# Get child-element from nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div-structure like this:

```
<div id="company1">
  <div class="space m-d p-r s-t">
    <div class="zzr">
      <div class="myTemplate">abc123</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the content form the class "`myTemplate`" over my "`id`"-div "`company1`"

Is it necessary to call all classes in my selector? Would be not good becaus of responsive design, the classes will change. So I woul prefer to call the "#company1" and then directly the "myTemplate". Tried this, but the content is empty and also the selector.

```
$('#company-'+currentTabIndex).children('.myTemplate').html()
//currentTabIndex has the current Tab-Index, in this case: 1
```

Comment: THANKS TO ALL for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the `id` property in your HTML has no `-` in it. Secondly, `children` looks at direct descendants, whereas you need to use `find()`:

```
$('#company' + currentTabIndex).find('.myTemplate').html()
```

That said, you can use a single selector and remove the `find()` completely:

```
$('#company' + currentTabIndex + ' .myTemplate').html()
```

Comment: Nice catch on the `-`!

Answer (score 2):

You want [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find), not [`.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children):

```
$('#company-'+currentTabIndex).find('.myTemplate').html()
```

`.find` looks for *descendant* elements. `.children` just looks for immediate children.

Or a single selector using the [*descendant combinator*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) (the space before `.myTemplate` below — gotta love that name):

```
$('#company-' + currentTabIndex + ' .myTemplate').html()
```

See also [Rory's note about the `-` in your selector, which isn't in your `id`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28738184/157247). Either remove it from the selector, or add it to the `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Children searches only for single level child elements, you have to use `find()`.

```
$('#company-'+currentTabIndex).find('.myTemplate').html()
```

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .children() method allows us to search through the children of these
>   elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the
>   matching elements. The .children() method differs from .find() in that
>   .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while
>   .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant
>   elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Reference: [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) - [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 $('#company-'+currentTabIndex).children('.myTemplate').html();
```

Try

```
$('#company'+currentTabIndex).find('.myTemplate').html(); //remove '-' from the selector
```

Use `.find()` instead of `.children()` as shown above.